# Returning pointer to an array of arrays created using new

Tags: c++

I have created an array of arrays using `char (*H)[N] = new char[M][N];`
I want to return this pointer to my main function. My question is what should the function return type be in this case? Am I allowed to have a return type as a pointer to an array of arrays.

Comment: You may return a pointer to any data type.

Comment: Is `new char[M][N]` even legal? I thought you can't allocate a multi-dimensional array with a single `new` call, or am I wrong?

Comment: @RemyLebeau It's legal, but the inner dimension size must be compile time constant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Am I allowed to have a return type as a pointer to an array of arrays.

Yes. One way to do that would be to define a type alias and use it as the return type.

```
using MyArrayPointer = char (*)[N];

MyArrayPointer foo()
{
   auto ptr = new char[M][N];
   return ptr;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

> Am I allowed to have a return type as a pointer to an array of arrays.

Yes, this would be the syntax for your particular case:

```
char (*get_array())[N] {
  return H;
}
```

But you really should consider using either `std::unique_ptr<char[N]>` or `std::array<std::array<char, N>, M>`.